# Transaction for ExecuteSqlCommand in Azure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I am using EF 6 with a Azure Sql database. According to Microsoft, user initiated transactions are not supported (ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn307226#transactions)

Now, with EF 6, `ExecuteSqlCommand` is wrapped in a transaction by default:

> Starting with EF6 Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() by default will wrap the command in a transaction if one was not already present. (ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx)

Given my scenario, should I always suppress `ExecuteSqlCommand` transactional behaviour like this:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, @"TRUNCATE TABLE Person;");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This statement that you are referring to applies only to retry strategies:

> When you have configured an execution strategy that results in retries ...

The article you linked to is not specific to Azure. Azure SQL Database supports transactions.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but is it not advisable to use a retry execution strategy when working with an Azure SQL Database? As such, if I do use such a strategy, is there any concern about `ExecuteSqlCommand`'s default behaviour, or am I just being paranoid and mis-reading things?

Comment: Retry must happen at the transaction level. For that reason I consider retry support in EF quite pointless. EF cannot retry your transaction, it can retry a single query or SaveChanges call. It's the wrong level to retry at. If you let EF control transactions it will use one tran per query/save. Retry strategies support that. But I advise you to use proper transactions and retry yourself (maybe using a simple helper method).; EF can wrap a retry loop around it's own code. But it cannot wrap a retry loop around *your* code. So any single call to EF can be retried but multiple calls cannot.

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not you want to use `TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction` depends on whether you want there to be a transaction during the scope of the command. This is only relevant (as far as I know) if you have multiple T-SQL statements in the batch.

In other words, if your execution strategy has retries and want several statements to be executed within a transaction, they must be all in a single batch like below.

In order for a transaction to span multiple batches, it would have to be created with `db.Database.BeginTransaction`. It is this explicit `BeginTransaction` that [the document you linked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn307226#transactions) explains is not allowed in combination with retries. The transaction that is created by `TransactionalBehavior.EnsureTransaction` is allowed regardless of retry policy (because it's fully managed by EF).

```
// INSERT is rolled back due to error
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    TransactionalBehavior.EnsureTransaction,
    @"INSERT INTO MyTable (i) VALUES (1)
    RAISERROR('This exception was intentionally thrown', 16, 1)");

// INSERT is committed
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction,
    @"INSERT INTO MyTable (i) VALUES (1)
    RAISERROR('This exception was intentionally thrown', 16, 1)");
```

Test program is below.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //c:>sqlcmd -E
        //1> create database EFTransaction
        //2> go
        //1> use EFTransaction
        //2> go
        //Changed database context to 'EFTransaction'.
        //1> create table MyTable (i int primary key)
        //2> go
        const string connectionString = "Server=(local);Database=EFTransaction;Integrated Security=SSPI";

        using (DbContext context = new DbContext(connectionString))
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction,
                @"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables where name = 'MyTable')
                    DROP TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
                CREATE TABLE MyTable (i INT PRIMARY KEY)");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Insert one row."); 
        using (DbContext context = new DbContext(connectionString))
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                TransactionalBehavior.EnsureTransaction,
                @"INSERT INTO MyTable (i) VALUES (0)");
            // Notice that there is no explicit COMMIT command required.
        }

        // Sanity check in a different connection that the row really was committed
        using (DbContext context = new DbContext(connectionString))
        {
            int rows = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable").Single();
            Console.WriteLine("Rows: {0}", rows); // Rows: 1
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Insert one row and then throw an error, all within a transaction.");
        Console.WriteLine("The error should cause the insert to be rolled back, so there should be no new rows");
        using (DbContext context = new DbContext(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                    TransactionalBehavior.EnsureTransaction,
                    @"INSERT INTO MyTable (i) VALUES (1)
                    RAISERROR('This exception was intentionally thrown', 16, 1)");
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            int rows = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable").Single();
            Console.WriteLine("Rows: {0}", rows); // Rows: 1
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Insert one row and then throw an error, all within a transaction.");
        Console.WriteLine("The error will not cause the insert to be rolled back, so there should be 1 new row");
        using (DbContext context = new DbContext(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                    TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction,
                    @"INSERT INTO MyTable (i) VALUES (1)
                    RAISERROR('This exception was intentionally thrown', 16, 1)");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            int rows = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable").Single();
            Console.WriteLine("Rows: {0}", rows); // Rows: 2
        }
    }
```